# Binding to NSMatrix for BOOL attributes

Tags: objective-c, binding, boolean, nsmatrix

I have a simple core-data entity that has a Boolean attribute called `subscribedToNewsletter`.  I have designed my UI to represent this field as a radio button group with `Yes`/`No` as the text values (and obviously `YES`/`NO` as the backing BOOL values).

I have always considered myself to have excellent google-fu, but for the life of me, I am unable to find any clear documentation on:

- how to bind the selected value of the NSMatrix (or is it the cell?) back to a YES/NO value
- how to bind the textual values (if indeed I do need to; I know there are only ever going to be two values - surely they can be hard-coded in Interface Builder, or not?)

Next up will be how to bind a radio group (with `Male/Female` text) to a String field called `gender` that has `M` and `F` as possible values - but I digress.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you solve your problem of "how to bind a radio group (with Male/Female text) to a String field called gender that has M and F as possible values"? What if there are more than 2 choices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I got no answers because a) it is such a stupid question, or b) no-one in the world knows how.  The latter doesn't strike me as likely, so I can only presume the first :)

Anyway just in case there others as stupid as me, I thought I'd give some feedback on how I managed to achieve it.

In Interface Builder, I created a NSMatrix with two radio button cells with "Yes" and "No" as the text for each respectively.  In the Attributes Inspector (command-1), make sure the Tag field is set to 1 for the "Yes" button cell, and set to 0 for the "No" button cell.  Then, in the Bindings Inspector (command-4) bind the SelectedTag field for the **matrix** to the Boolean property on your entity.  Easy as pie.

I make no claims that this is the best way... just that it is effective.

Answer (score -1):

I have found one solution for this part-

> how to bind the selected value of the
> NSMatrix (or is it the cell?) back to
> a YES/NO value

Here is the link to the problem which I faced and its solution- [NSMatrix simple binding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360315/nsmatrix-simple-binding-question/6372676#6372676)

Hope this helps !