# NSMatrix simple binding question

Tags: cocoa-bindings, nsmatrix

I am trying a sample application in which I have taken following controls:

i.  NSMatrix (with 2 elements, serving as radio button)

ii. Button (which when clicked generates action based on radio button selected)

My questions are-

> In IB, can we bind each button cell of
>   NSMatrix to a single bool variable,
>   say- firstElementValue, such that when
>   user selects first button cell in
>   NSMatrix, firstElementValue is YES and
>   when user selects second button cell
>   in NSMatrix, firstElementValue is NO.

or

> Is there any other effective way to
>   achieve this ?

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by setting NSNegateBoolean as value transformer for one of the radio button cells :)